# Joint distribution of positive weights with sum unity and an equality constraint.

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I have a vector of positive weights $a=(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)'$ such that $a_2=a_3$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=1$. Is there any way to construct a joint sampling distribution for $a$ with a compact functional form ?

P.S. The context of this problem follows from a StackOverflow
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599799/sampling-of-positive-weights-with-sum-unity-and-an-equality-constraint/32600703#32600703). There @josilber gave a very nice and easy sampling mechanism to sample this kind of weights.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the expression into ($b_1$ + $b_2$ + $b_3$ = 1) and assume that $b_i$ is $U(0,1)$, you could clearly see it is Dirichlet distribution. It could be sampled from gammavariates with parameter vector $\vec{\alpha}=1$. After sampling reassign $a_1$ = $b_1$, $a_2$ = $b_2$/2, $a_3$ = $b_2$/2, $a_4$ = $b_3$

Comment: Thanks. I think I got your point - we can assume $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ to be $Dirichlet(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ and $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ will have the same distribution as $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ with $a_2=a_3$. By the way why you are telling each A, B, C follows U(0,1) ? They do not. Only after two transformations ($-ln(x_i)$ and $x_i/\sum x_i$) on U(0,1) variate we can get Dirichlet.

Comment: @SoumenDey `By the way why you are telling each A, B, C follows U(0,1) ? ` Well, PDF is a product of $x^{\alpha_i-1}_i$, and lies within $0...1$ range. In case of $\vec{\alpha}=1$ PDF is constant thus making it $U(0,1)$, isn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Comment: @SoumenDey No, I'm most likely wrong. While $X_i$ is within $[0...1]$ interval and PDF is constant (for $\alpha=1$), mean and variance is different from $U(0,1)$.